# IBM x360 DVD drive?

Tags: hardware, ibm-xseries, optical-media

My x360 server has only a CD drive in it.

I wish to upgrade and install a DVD drive, so it is easier for me to install software without sharing my workstation DVD drive all the time.

According to IBM ServerProven Compatibility, only those two are compatible with my x360:

- 10K3798
- 22P7047

Reference: [x360 (8686) compatibility](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/info/x86servers/serverproven/compat/us/xseries_old/x360.html)

Is it all that fits, or can I use any IBM DVD laptop drive to fit it, like faster than only 8x?

Comment: These are the types of questions that leave me scratching my head. You have a list of supported devices but you want to know if an unsupported device will work. Why? Even if it does work why would you want to put an unsupported device in your server?

Comment: Because the supported hardware might be harder to find, and is also only 8x fast, while others like 24x IBM Laptop drive are easier to find. Plus, some hardware, though not listed in the ServerProven compatibility, might as well work. So, I am simply asking from real people with real experience, as I am no sysadmin.

Comment: Understood. My point being that installing unsupported devices may void any warranty or service contract, may cause the system to become unstable, or may cause other system components to malfunction, so why risk it, regardless of whether or not others have gotten it to work?

Comment: Since my server is quite old (x360), I have no warranty on it and never had from purchase. I bought it for my own personal needs as a software engineer willing to try and to test some solutions that demand a server to represent real-life environments. And since 8x is quite slow for a DVD, and the x360 server capable of eating more than 8x, I thought of perhaps putting a faster drive into it, to make it less a pain to install ESX, etc. Perhaps I am going the wrong way, which it sounds like reading your point of view and TheCleaner's. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a usb drive like this one [http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Portable-External-SE-218CB-RSBS/dp/B00DBV28TG/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DBV28TG) or a USB thumb drive.  Don't mess with replacing the internal drive for what amounts to a very rarely used device in a server (hence the reason a lot of the newer IBM servers don't even come with a DVD/CD drive standard).

If you insist on replacing the internal one, do like Joeqwerty says and stick with what is on the ServerProven list if you want support from IBM on it.

Comment: A USB DVD drive sounds like a much better solution then trying to use an unsupported drive.

Comment: Nothing faster than 8x DVD drive for a server? How may you install stuff on your server if no DVD/CD drives on it?

Comment: The one I pointed out is plenty fast at 8x and doesn't require external power.  Don't get hung up on the "Xx speed" stuff.  You can plug it into the USB port and boot to it for an OS/ServerGuide install, or plug it in and access it as an additional drive in Windows or mount it in Linux.  I'm not really sure what you are asking at this point.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion that I created. I wonder how you may install OSes on your server if no DVD drives come with it (for the newer IBM servers which don't come with a optical drive).

Comment: As for the speed, the Xx, I'll take it granted not to rely on it much for servers. Thanks! (+1)

Comment: @WillMarcouiller - on new servers that don't come with an optical drive you either buy an external usb optical drive like I linked to or use a USB thumb drive.  You can create bootable usb thumb drives for Serverguide, OS, etc. nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for those information, TheCleaner! =) I shall remind this.